# MPN extraction regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need a help with regex for MPN patterns, mostly for this one:

```
Bosch HBA13B250B Built-in Electric Single Oven
```

so 3 letters followed by at least 1 digit and then until word boundry is reached should extract

```
HBA13B250B
```

Do you have any ideas how to put it into regex pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
preg_match('#\b([A-Z]{3}[0-9].*?)\b#', $text, $match);
```

or, to better restrict possible values:

```
preg_match('#\b([A-Z]{3}[0-9][0-9A-Z]*)\b#', $text, $match);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$text = "Bosch HBA13B250B Built-in Electric Single Oven";
$pattern = '/\b([A-Z]{3}[0-9]+.*)\b/i';

echo "Matches: " . preg_match($pattern, $text);
```

Comment: Sorry - typo - should be fixed now!